# How does Twitter implement its Tweet Box?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, range, selection

I'm trying to implement something like Twitter's tweet box, specifically:

- Automatically highlights text in a red background when the overall length exceeds 140 characters.
- Automatically highlights links, mentions, and hashtags in blue.

These should happen automatically aka when a user types.

By the semantic markup I'm seeing on Twitter, it looks like they're using a `contentEditable` div. And the DOM inside is modified whenever a mention/hashtag/link is detected, or when the length is exceeded over 140 characters:

```
<div aria-labelledby="tweet-box-mini-home-profile-label" id="tweet-box-mini-home-profile" class="tweet-box rich-editor  notie" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" dir="ltr" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-dropdown-6">
    <div>hello world <a class="twitter-atreply pretty-link" href="/testMention" role="presentation"><s>@</s>testMention</a> text <a href="/search?q=%23helloWorld" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link" role="presentation"><s>#</s>helloWorld</a> text <a href="http://www.google.com" class="twitter-timeline-link" role="presentation">http://www.google.com</a> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text <em>overflow red text here</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I have done so far**

Currently, I'm using a contentEditable field. It triggers a function `onChange/onInput` that parses the text. Check if it has a username/link/hashtag via regexr and replace them with the respective tags (I'm just using a simple `<i>` tag to enclose username and hashtag for now). 
**The problem I'm having is that because I'm changing/modifying the DOM of the contentEditable, the caret cursor position becomes lost.**
I looked at this thread [Persisting the changes of range objects after selection in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949059/persisting-the-changes-of-range-objects-after-selection-in-html/13950376#13950376) and it works fine only if the DOM isn't changed (which it is in my case, surrounding tags/hashtags with `<i>` tags, links with `<a>` tags, and overflow with `<b>` tags.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lsqjkjb/

Does anyone have any alternative solutions/approaches on how to tackle this problem? Maybe I shouldn't use `contentEditable`? Or some way that doesn't directly modify the DOM of the `contentEditable` field so the caret position is maintained? Any help would be appreciated! I tried playing around with `window.getSelection()` and saving it before DOM change, but it always seem to reset after DOM changes are applied.

Comment: Feel free to mess with [my fork here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/y59smkj2/4/). I can't figure it out either. It seems like Twitter is using a hidden div to track caret movements somehow. It's really hard to capture the correct node and offset while things are changing.

Comment: Example solution for highlighting excess characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20335351/96100

Comment: Hi 
Even I'm also trying to implement same like twitter box functionality, have you got the solution for cursor issue. if the user enters '#' I'm hitting search API to get the hashtags. here is my sample code [https://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/5a9c4f87/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/5a9c4f87/6/)
  @Austin Mullins

Answer (score 9):

What I did is kind of a hack but works quite well as a workaround solution.

I've got a simple textarea (not contenteditable because of what's next, I'll explain below) and a div which is absolute positioned behind the textarea. Using javascript, I copy the content from the textarea to the div while splitting it at 140 chars and putting all extra characters inside an `<em />` tag.

Well, it's a little bit more complicated because twitter algorithm to compute a tweet length is different (links doesn't count as their real value, because of t.co url shortening). The exact method can be found as part of the official [twitter/twitter-txt repository](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js).

## Step-by-step code.

Wrap a simple textarea into a div to simplify the css:

```
<div class="tweet-composer">
  <textarea class="editor-textarea js-keeper-editor">This is some text that will be highlight when longer than 20 characters. Like twitter. Type something...</textarea>
  <div class="js-keeper-placeholder-back"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is just making the textarea and the div right above each other and highlight the text.

```
.tweet-composer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.js-keeper-editor,
.js-keeper-placeholder-back {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px; /* Same font for both. */
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.js-keeper-placeholder-back {
  bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: -1;
}

.js-keeper-placeholder-back em {
  background: #fcc !important;
}
```

Now the fun part, this is implemented using jQuery but that's not the important thing.

```
if (0 > remainingLength) {
  // Split value if greater than 
  var allowedValuePart = currentValue.slice(0, realLength),
      refusedValuePart = currentValue.slice(realLength)
  ;

  // Fill the hidden div.
  $placeholderBacker.html(allowedValuePart + '<em>' + refusedValuePart + '</em>');
} else {
  $placeholderBacker.html('');
}
```

Add some event handler on change, and te common document ready and you're done. See the codepen link below.

Note that the div placed behind can be created using js too, when loading the page:

```
// Create a pseudo-element that will be hidden behind the placeholder.
var $placeholderBacker = $('<div class="js-keeper-placeholder-back"></div>');
$placeholderBacker.insertAfter($textarea);
```

## Full example

*See working example over here:*
http://codepen.io/hussard/pen/EZvaBZ

Comment: This is a very good option if you're okay using a textarea.  The only other way is a more complex solution using a contentEditable.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a direct answer with source code building the part of your application to your spec.

This is **really** not an *easy* thing to do.

You're right - the way to solving this problem is to use a `contenteditable="true"` container.  But I'm afraid that from there it gets much [much more complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feUYwoLhE_4).

Enter DraftJS - A javascript solution to rich-text editing which does most of the heavy lifting for you.

Both of my solutions below require the use of both React and DraftJS

---

### The Plug-&-Play Solution:

The **React** + **DraftJS** + **Someone Else's "Plugin"** solution is already here.  You can check out [draft-js-plugins.com](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/).  And [here's the Github source code](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins).

Personally, I wouldn't go this way.  I would rather study their GitHub source code and implement my own DraftJS [`entities`](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-entities.html).  Because I think that React-JS-Plugins feels a little bit clunky and overweight for just Links and Mentions.  Plus, where are you "mentioning" from?  Your own Application?  Twitter?  Doing it this way lets you have control over where you're grabbing the so-called "mentions".

---

### The DIY Solution:

The best way I have found is to build your own set of working [`entities`](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-entities.html) on top of a DraftJS based rich-text editor.

This of course also requires that you're using [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Forgive me for not actually building a complete set of working code.  I was interested in doing something similar for an App I'm building in Meteor with React on the front-end.  So this really made sense to me because I'd only be adding one more library (DraftJS) and the rest would be my custom [`entities`](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-entities.html) coded out.

Comment: This suggestion is still relevant in 2022, and helped me solve this difficult issue.  Can't express how helpful it was, thank you.  I ended up doing mostly the plug in play with a little customizing.   to anyone reading this, This link, which is just a little farther down the path, may help you get started: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention

Comment: @DORRITO – It's excellent to know that [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) has grown and come a long way since I wrote this answer. Your comment not only **made my day** _(thank you)_ but it prompted me to update this answer. Now, DraftJS is officially used in production across the board at Facebook for both `Status Updates` and `Comment` inputs, `Notes`, and `Messenger.com`. It also has `Documentation`, an `API Reference`, its own `Twitter account`, and even a [`Stackoverflow tag`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draftjs) - none of which existed when I posted this answer years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is *really* not an easy thing to do. I've been struggling with it for the past few days, and I'm not very close to a solution.

Your best drop-in solution currently is the [At.js library](https://github.com/ichord/At.js), which is still being maintained, but definitely isn't perfect. One of the examples shows how you can *kind of* do a text highlight.

The most annoying part of this problem is that Twitter has a beautiful solution that seemingly works perfectly staring us right in the face. I took some time investigating the way they implement their "tweet box," and it's definitely not trivial. It looks like they're doing almost everything manually, including emulating undo/redo functionality, intercepting copy/pastes, providing custom code for IE/W3C, custom-coding Mac/PC, and more. They use a contenteditable div, which is in-and-of-itself problematic due to differences in browser implementations. It's pretty impressive, actually.

Here's the most relevant (obfuscated, unfortunately) code, taken from Twitter's boot JavaScript file (found by inspecting the header of the logged-in Twitter homepage). I didn't want to directly copy and paste the link, in case it's personalized to my Twitter account.

```
define("app/utils/html_text", ["module", "require", "exports"], function(module, require, exports) {
    function isTextNode(a) {
        return a.nodeType == 3 || a.nodeType == 4
    }

    function isElementNode(a) {
        return a.nodeType == 1
    }

    function isBrNode(a) {
        return isElementNode(a) && a.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "br"
    }

    function isOutsideContainer(a, b) {
        while (a !== b) {
            if (!a) return !0;
            a = a.parentNode
        }
    }
    var useW3CRange = window.getSelection,
        useMsftTextRange = !useW3CRange && document.selection,
        useIeHtmlFix = navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
        NBSP_REGEX = /[\xa0\n\t]/g,
        CRLF_REGEX = /\r\n/g,
        LINES_REGEX = /(.*?)\n/g,
        SP_LEADING_OR_FOLLOWING_CLOSE_TAG_OR_PRECEDING_A_SP_REGEX = /^ |(<\/[^>]+>) | (?= )/g,
        SP_LEADING_OR_TRAILING_OR_FOLLOWING_A_SP_REGEX = /^ | $|( ) /g,
        MAX_OFFSET = Number.MAX_VALUE,
        htmlText = function(a, b) {
            function c(a, c) {
                function h(a) {
                    var i = d.length;
                    if (isTextNode(a)) {
                        var j = a.nodeValue.replace(NBSP_REGEX, " "),
                            k = j.length;
                        k && (d += j, e = !0), c(a, !0, 0, i, i + k)
                    } else if (isElementNode(a)) {
                        c(a, !1, 0, i, i);
                        if (isBrNode(a)) a == f ? g = !0 : (d += "\n", e = !1);
                        else {
                            var l = a.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(a, ""),
                                m = l.display == "block";
                            m && b.msie && (e = !0);
                            for (var n = a.firstChild, o = 1; n; n = n.nextSibling, o++) {
                                h(n);
                                if (g) return;
                                i = d.length, c(a, !1, o, i, i)
                            }
                            g || a == f ? g = !0 : m && e && (d += "\n", e = !1)
                        }
                    }
                }
                var d = "",
                    e, f, g;
                for (var i = a; i && isElementNode(i); i = i.lastChild) f = i;
                return h(a), d
            }

            function d(a, b) {
                var d = null,
                    e = b.length - 1;
                if (useW3CRange) {
                    var f = b.map(function() {
                            return {}
                        }),
                        g;
                    c(a, function(a, c, d, h, i) {
                        g || f.forEach(function(f, j) {
                            var k = b[j];
                            h <= k && !isBrNode(a) && (f.node = a, f.offset = c ? Math.min(k, i) - h : d, g = c && j == e && i >= k)
                        })
                    }), f[0].node && f[e].node && (d = document.createRange(), d.setStart(f[0].node, f[0].offset), d.setEnd(f[e].node, f[e].offset))
                } else if (useMsftTextRange) {
                    var h = document.body.createTextRange();
                    h.moveToElementText(a), d = h.duplicate();
                    if (b[0] == MAX_OFFSET) d.setEndPoint("StartToEnd", h);
                    else {
                        d.move("character", b[0]);
                        var i = e && b[1] - b[0];
                        i > 0 && d.moveEnd("character", i), h.inRange(d) || d.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", h)
                    }
                }
                return d
            }

            function e() {
                return document.body.contains(a)
            }

            function f(b) {
                a.innerHTML = b;
                if (useIeHtmlFix)
                    for (var c = a.firstChild; c; c = c.nextSibling) isElementNode(c) && c.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "p" && c.innerHTML == "" && (c.innerText = "")
            }

            function g(a, b) {
                return a.map(function(a) {
                    return Math.min(a, b.length)
                })
            }

            function h() {
                var b = getSelection();
                if (b.rangeCount !== 1) return null;
                var d = b.getRangeAt(0);
                if (isOutsideContainer(d.commonAncestorContainer, a)) return null;
                var e = [{
                    node: d.startContainer,
                    offset: d.startOffset
                }];
                d.collapsed || e.push({
                    node: d.endContainer,
                    offset: d.endOffset
                });
                var f = e.map(function() {
                        return MAX_OFFSET
                    }),
                    h = c(a, function(a, b, c, d) {
                        e.forEach(function(e, g) {
                            f[g] == MAX_OFFSET && a == e.node && (b || c == e.offset) && (f[g] = d + (b ? e.offset : 0))
                        })
                    });
                return g(f, h)
            }

            function i() {
                var b = document.selection.createRange();
                if (isOutsideContainer(b.parentElement(), a)) return null;
                var d = ["Start"];
                b.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", b) && d.push("End");
                var e = d.map(function() {
                        return MAX_OFFSET
                    }),
                    f = document.body.createTextRange(),
                    h = c(a, function(c, g, h, i) {
                        function j(a, c) {
                            if (e[c] < MAX_OFFSET) return;
                            var d = f.compareEndPoints("StartTo" + a, b);
                            if (d > 0) return;
                            var g = f.compareEndPoints("EndTo" + a, b);
                            if (g < 0) return;
                            var h = f.duplicate();
                            h.setEndPoint("EndTo" + a, b), e[c] = i + h.text.length, c && !g && e[c]++
                        }!g && !h && c != a && (f.moveToElementText(c), d.forEach(j))
                    });
                return g(e, h)
            }
            return {
                getHtml: function() {
                    if (useIeHtmlFix) {
                        var b = "",
                            c = document.createElement("div");
                        for (var d = a.firstChild; d; d = d.nextSibling) isTextNode(d) ? (c.innerText = d.nodeValue, b += c.innerHTML) : b += d.outerHTML.replace(CRLF_REGEX, "");
                        return b
                    }
                    return a.innerHTML
                },
                setHtml: function(a) {
                    f(a)
                },
                getText: function() {
                    return c(a, function() {})
                },
                setTextWithMarkup: function(a) {
                    f((a + "\n").replace(LINES_REGEX, function(a, c) {
                        return b.mozilla || b.msie ? (c = c.replace(SP_LEADING_OR_FOLLOWING_CLOSE_TAG_OR_PRECEDING_A_SP_REGEX, "$1&nbsp;"), b.mozilla ? c + "<BR>" : "<P>" + c + "</P>") : (c = (c || "<br>").replace(SP_LEADING_OR_TRAILING_OR_FOLLOWING_A_SP_REGEX, "$1&nbsp;"), b.opera ? "<p>" + c + "</p>" : "<div>" + c + "</div>")
                    }))
                },
                getSelectionOffsets: function() {
                    var a = null;
                    return e() && (useW3CRange ? a = h() : useMsftTextRange && (a = i())), a
                },
                setSelectionOffsets: function(b) {
                    if (b && e()) {
                        var c = d(a, b);
                        if (c)
                            if (useW3CRange) {
                                var f = window.getSelection();
                                f.removeAllRanges(), f.addRange(c)
                            } else useMsftTextRange && c.select()
                    }
                },
                emphasizeText: function(b) {
                    var f = [];
                    b && b.length > 1 && e() && (c(a, function(a, c, d, e, g) {
                        if (c) {
                            var h = Math.max(e, b[0]),
                                i = Math.min(g, b[1]);
                            i > h && f.push([h, i])
                        }
                    }), f.forEach(function(b) {
                        var c = d(a, b);
                        c && (useW3CRange ? c.surroundContents(document.createElement("em")) : useMsftTextRange && c.execCommand("italic", !1, null))
                    }))
                }
            }
        };
    module.exports = htmlText
});








define("app/utils/tweet_helper", ["module", "require", "exports", "lib/twitter-text", "core/utils", "app/data/user_info"], function(module, require, exports) {
    var twitterText = require("lib/twitter-text"),
        utils = require("core/utils"),
        userInfo = require("app/data/user_info"),
        VALID_PROTOCOL_PREFIX_REGEX = /^https?:\/\//i,
        tweetHelper = {
            extractMentionsForReply: function(a, b) {
                var c = a.attr("data-screen-name"),
                    d = a.attr("data-retweeter"),
                    e = a.attr("data-mentions") ? a.attr("data-mentions").split(" ") : [],
                    f = a.attr("data-tagged") ? a.attr("data-tagged").split(" ") : [];
                e = e.concat(f);
                var g = [c, b, d];
                return e = e.filter(function(a) {
                    return g.indexOf(a) < 0
                }), d && d != c && d != b && e.unshift(d), (!e.length || c != b) && e.unshift(c), e
            },
            linkify: function(a, b) {
                return b = utils.merge({
                    hashtagClass: "twitter-hashtag pretty-link",
                    hashtagUrlBase: "/search?q=%23",
                    symbolTag: "s",
                    textWithSymbolTag: "b",
                    cashtagClass: "twitter-cashtag pretty-link",
                    cashtagUrlBase: "/search?q=%24",
                    usernameClass: "twitter-atreply pretty-link",
                    usernameUrlBase: "/",
                    usernameIncludeSymbol: !0,
                    listClass: "twitter-listname pretty-link",
                    urlClass: "twitter-timeline-link",
                    urlTarget: "_blank",
                    suppressNoFollow: !0,
                    htmlEscapeNonEntities: !0
                }, b || {}), twitterText.autoLinkEntities(a, twitterText.extractEntitiesWithIndices(a), b)
            }
        };
    module.exports = tweetHelper
});










define("app/ui/compose/with_rich_editor", ["module", "require", "exports", "app/utils/file", "app/utils/html_text", "app/utils/tweet_helper", "lib/twitter-text"], function(module, require, exports) {
    function withRichEditor() {
        this.defaultAttrs({
            richSelector: "div.rich-editor",
            linksSelector: "a",
            normalizerSelector: "div.rich-normalizer",
            $browser: $.browser
        }), this.linkify = function(a) {
            var b = {
                urlTarget: null,
                textWithSymbolTag: RENDER_URLS_AS_PRETTY_LINKS ? "b" : "",
                linkAttributeBlock: function(a, b) {
                    var c = a.screenName || a.url;
                    c && (this.urlAndMentionsCharCount += c.length + 2), delete b.title, delete b["data-screen-name"], b.dir = a.hashtag && this.shouldBeRTL(a.hashtag, 0) ? "rtl" : "ltr", b.role = "presentation"
                }.bind(this)
            };
            return this.urlAndMentionsCharCount = 0, tweetHelper.linkify(a, b)
        }, this.around("setSelection", function(a, b) {
            b && this.setSelectionIfFocused(b)
        }), this.around("setCursorPosition", function(a, b) {
            b === undefined && (b = this.attr.cursorPosition), b === undefined && (b = MAX_OFFSET), this.setSelectionIfFocused([b])
        }), this.around("detectUpdatedText", function(a, b, c) {
            var d = this.htmlRich.getHtml(),
                e = this.htmlRich.getSelectionOffsets() || [MAX_OFFSET],
                f = c !== undefined;
            if (d === this.prevHtml && e[0] === this.prevSelectionOffset && !b && !f) return;
            var g = f ? c : this.htmlRich.getText(),
                h = g.replace(INVALID_CHARS_REGEX, "");
            (f || !(!d && !this.hasFocus() || this.$text.attr("data-in-composition"))) && this.reformatHtml(h, d, e, f);
            if (b || this.cleanedText != h || this.prevSelectionOffset != e[0]) this.prevSelectionOffset = e[0], this.updateCleanedTextAndOffset(h, e[0])
        }), this.reformatHtml = function(a, b, c, d) {
            this.htmlNormalizer.setTextWithMarkup(this.linkify(a)), this.interceptDataImageInContent();
            var e = this.shouldBeRTL(a, this.urlAndMentionsCharCount);
            this.$text.attr("dir", e ? "rtl" : "ltr"), this.$normalizer.find(e ? "[dir=rtl]" : "[dir=ltr]").removeAttr("dir"), RENDER_URLS_AS_PRETTY_LINKS && this.$normalizer.find(".twitter-timeline-link").wrapInner("<b>").addClass("pretty-link");
            var f = this.getMaxLengthOffset(a);
            f >= 0 && (this.htmlNormalizer.emphasizeText([f, MAX_OFFSET]), this.$normalizer.find("em").each(function() {
                this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(TRAILING_SINGLE_SPACE_REGEX, "Â ")
            }));
            var g = this.htmlNormalizer.getHtml();
            if (g !== b) {
                var h = d && !this.isFocusing && this.hasFocus();
                h && this.$text.addClass("fake-focus").blur(), this.htmlRich.setHtml(g), h && this.$text.focus().removeClass("fake-focus"), this.setSelectionIfFocused(c)
            }
            this.prevHtml = g
        }, this.interceptDataImageInContent = function() {
            if (!this.triggerGotImageData) return;
            this.$text.find("img").filter(function(a, b) {
                return b.src.match(/^data:/)
            }).first().each(function(a, b) {
                var c = file.getBlobFromDataUri(b.src);
                file.getFileData("pasted.png", c).then(this.triggerGotImageData.bind(this))
            }.bind(this))
        }, this.getMaxLengthOffset = function(a) {
            var b = this.getLength(a),
                c = this.attr.maxLength;
            if (b <= c) return -1;
            c += twitterText.getUnicodeTextLength(a) - b;
            var d = [{
                indices: [c, c]
            }];
            return twitterText.modifyIndicesFromUnicodeToUTF16(a, d), d[0].indices[0]
        }, this.setSelectionIfFocused = function(a) {
            this.hasFocus() ? (this.previousSelection = null, this.htmlRich.setSelectionOffsets(a)) : this.previousSelection = a
        }, this.selectPrevCharOnBackspace = function(a) {
            if (a.which == 8 && !a.ctrlKey) {
                var b = this.htmlRich.getSelectionOffsets();
                b && b[0] != MAX_OFFSET && b.length == 1 && (b[0] ? this.setSelectionIfFocused([b[0] - 1, b[0]]) : this.stopEvent(a))
            }
        }, this.emulateCommandArrow = function(a) {
            if (a.metaKey && !a.shiftKey && (a.which == 37 || a.which == 39)) {
                var b = a.which == 37;
                this.htmlRich.setSelectionOffsets([b ? 0 : MAX_OFFSET]), this.$text.scrollTop(b ? 0 : this.$text[0].scrollHeight), this.stopEvent(a)
            }
        }, this.stopEvent = function(a) {
            a.preventDefault(), a.stopPropagation()
        }, this.saveUndoStateDeferred = function(a) {
            if (a.type == "mousemove" && a.which != 1) return;
            setTimeout(function() {
                this.detectUpdatedText(), this.saveUndoState()
            }.bind(this), 0)
        }, this.clearUndoState = function() {
            this.undoHistory = [], this.undoIndex = -1
        }, this.saveUndoState = function() {
            var a = this.htmlRich.getText(),
                b = this.htmlRich.getSelectionOffsets() || [a.length],
                c = this.undoHistory,
                d = c[this.undoIndex];
            !d || d[0] !== a ? c.splice(++this.undoIndex, c.length, [a, b]) : d && (d[1] = b)
        }, this.isUndoKey = function(a) {
            return this.isMac ? a.which == 90 && a.metaKey && !a.shiftKey && !a.ctrlKey && !a.altKey : a.which == 90 && a.ctrlKey && !a.shiftKey && !a.altKey
        }, this.emulateUndo = function(a) {
            this.isUndoKey(a) && (this.stopEvent(a), this.saveUndoState(), this.undoIndex > 0 && this.setUndoState(this.undoHistory[--this.undoIndex]))
        }, this.isRedoKey = function(a) {
            return this.isMac ? a.which == 90 && a.metaKey && a.shiftKey && !a.ctrlKey && !a.altKey : this.isWin ? a.which == 89 && a.ctrlKey && !a.shiftKey && !a.altKey : a.which == 90 && a.shiftKey && a.ctrlKey && !a.altKey
        }, this.emulateRedo = function(a) {
            var b = this.undoHistory,
                c = this.undoIndex;
            c < b.length - 1 && this.htmlRich.getText() !== b[c][0] && b.splice(c + 1, b.length), this.isRedoKey(a) && (this.stopEvent(a), c < b.length - 1 && this.setUndoState(b[++this.undoIndex]))
        }, this.setUndoState = function(a) {
            this.detectUpdatedText(!1, a[0]), this.htmlRich.setSelectionOffsets(a[1]), this.trigger("uiHideAutocomplete")
        }, this.undoStateAfterCursorMovement = function(a) {
            a.which >= 33 && a.which <= 40 && this.saveUndoStateDeferred(a)
        }, this.handleKeyDown = function(a) {
            this.isIE && this.selectPrevCharOnBackspace(a), this.attr.$browser.mozilla && this.emulateCommandArrow(a), this.undoStateAfterCursorMovement(a), this.emulateUndo(a), this.emulateRedo(a)
        }, this.interceptPaste = function(a) {
            if (a.originalEvent && a.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
                var b = a.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                (this.interceptImagePaste(b) || this.interceptTextPaste(b)) && a.preventDefault()
            }
        }, this.interceptImagePaste = function(a) {
            return this.triggerGotImageData && a.items && a.items.length === 1 && a.items[0].kind === "file" && a.items[0].type.indexOf("image/") === 0 ? (file.getFileData("pasted.png", a.items[0].getAsFile()).then(this.triggerGotImageData.bind(this)), !0) : !1
        }, this.interceptTextPaste = function(a) {
            var b = a.getData("text");
            return b && document.execCommand("insertHTML", !1, $("<div>").text(b).html().replace(LINE_FEEDS_REGEX, "<br>")) ? !0 : !1
        }, this.clearSelectionOnBlur = function() {
            window.getSelection && (this.previousSelection = this.htmlRich.getSelectionOffsets(), this.previousSelection && getSelection().removeAllRanges())
        }, this.restoreSelectionOnFocus = function() {
            this.previousSelection ? setTimeout(function() {
                this.htmlRich.setSelectionOffsets(this.previousSelection), this.previousSelection = null
            }.bind(this), 0) : this.previousSelection = null
        }, this.setFocusingState = function() {
            this.isFocusing = !0, setTimeout(function() {
                this.isFocusing = !1
            }.bind(this), 0)
        }, this.around("initTextNode", function(a) {
            this.isIE = this.attr.$browser.msie || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") > -1, this.$text = this.select("richSelector"), this.undoHistory = [
                ["", [0]]
            ], this.undoIndex = 0, this.htmlRich = htmlText(this.$text[0], this.attr.$browser), this.$text.toggleClass("notie", !this.isIE), this.$normalizer = this.select("normalizerSelector"), this.htmlNormalizer = htmlText(this.$normalizer[0], this.attr.$browser);
            var b = navigator.platform;
            this.isMac = b.indexOf("Mac") != -1, this.isWin = b.indexOf("Win") != -1, this.on(this.$text, "click", {
                linksSelector: this.stopEvent
            }), this.on(this.$text, "focusin", this.setFocusingState), this.on(this.$text, "keydown", this.handleKeyDown), this.on(this.$text, "focusout", this.ignoreDuringFakeFocus(this.clearSelectionOnBlur)), this.on(this.$text, "focusin", this.ignoreDuringFakeFocus(this.restoreSelectionOnFocus)), this.on(this.$text, "focusin", this.ignoreDuringFakeFocus(this.saveUndoStateDeferred)), this.on(this.$text, "cut paste drop", this.saveUndoState), this.on(this.$text, "cut paste drop mousedown mousemove", this.saveUndoStateDeferred), this.on("uiSaveUndoState", this.saveUndoState), this.on("uiClearUndoState", this.clearUndoState), this.on(this.$text, "paste", this.interceptPaste), this.detectUpdatedText()
        })
    }
    var file = require("app/utils/file"),
        htmlText = require("app/utils/html_text"),
        tweetHelper = require("app/utils/tweet_helper"),
        twitterText = require("lib/twitter-text");
    module.exports = withRichEditor;
    var INVALID_CHARS_REGEX = /[\uFFFE\uFEFF\uFFFF\u200E\u200F\u202A-\u202E\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/g,
        RENDER_URLS_AS_PRETTY_LINKS = $.browser.mozilla && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 2,
        TRAILING_SINGLE_SPACE_REGEX = / $/,
        LINE_FEEDS_REGEX = /\r\n|\n\r|\n/g,
        MAX_OFFSET = Number.MAX_VALUE
});













define("app/ui/compose/tweet_box_manager", ["module", "require", "exports", "app/ui/compose/tweet_box", "app/ui/compose/dm_composer", "app/ui/geo_picker", "core/component", "app/ui/compose/with_rich_editor"], function(module, require, exports) {
    function tweetBoxManager() {
        this.createTweetBoxAtTarget = function(a, b) {
            this.createTweetBox(a.target, b)
        }, this.createTweetBox = function(a, b) {
            var c = $(a);
            if (!((b.eventData || {}).scribeContext || {}).component) throw new Error("Please specify scribing component for tweet box.");
            c.find(".geo-picker").length > 0 && GeoPicker.attachTo(c.find(".geo-picker"), b, {
                parent: c
            });
            var d = c.find("div.rich-editor").length > 0 ? [withRichEditor] : [],
                e = (b.dmOnly ? DmComposer : TweetBox).mixin.apply(this, d),
                f = {
                    typeaheadData: this.attr.typeaheadData
                };
            e.attachTo(c, f, b)
        }, this.after("initialize", function() {
            this.on("uiInitTweetbox", this.createTweetBoxAtTarget)
        })
    }
    var TweetBox = require("app/ui/compose/tweet_box"),
        DmComposer = require("app/ui/compose/dm_composer"),
        GeoPicker = require("app/ui/geo_picker"),
        defineComponent = require("core/component"),
        withRichEditor = require("app/ui/compose/with_rich_editor"),
        TweetBoxManager = defineComponent(tweetBoxManager);
    module.exports = TweetBoxManager
});
```

Obviously, this "answer" doesn't solve anything, but hopefully could provide enough to (re-)spark a conversation about this topic.

Comment: Have you had any more progress with this @onsmith? I too have spent days looking into solutions that match the elegance of twitters tweetbox, without any real success.

Comment: @TimRicker DraftJS is really the only thing I think that solves this problem elegantly.  If you want something working right away you can use https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins either that or DraftJS with your own entities for the functionality you're looking for should do the trick.