# Building Twitter Like Dialogbox for input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am learning ReactJS and Material-UI and hence I have been working to build a semi twitter clone.

I am now hitting a road block in the sense that I can't figure how to build this input dialog box which can take all of text, video, photo, gif in same box.

Using `<Input />` I can provide individually what kind of input I have i.e. email, password, etc using `type`. But I am not sure how to design this particular dialog box to take multiple inputs.

Can you please show me a working code example ?

[image]

Comment: Please specify "which can take all of text, video, photo, gif in same box".

Comment: You might be looking for [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820293/how-does-twitter-implement-its-tweet-box

Comment: Thanks for those posts .. they are from 2017 .. hasn't much changed for past 2 years ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its 2019 and a lot of things have changed. This is a very rough and hacky implementation of how twitter has implemented. Its pretty simple.

---

### Working Demo Link

**For folks who want to just look at the code head over to** [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dawn-mxwwg?fontsize=14)

---

[image: tweetsheetpic]

**Note**: this was done very quickly to demonstrate what twitter has done under the hood.

The editor mainly consists of a `<textarea />` where text for the tweets are added.
Below the text area is an expanding div block which loops image files that are selected from file system.

As for the emoji, a standard emoji picker is used to select emojis and plain old javascript is used to add emojis at the current cursor position in the textarea.

I have skipped the gif picker, as its similar to the image picker, the only difference being, a modal is open to populate gifs from giphy. An api from giphy. can be easily integrated to achieve this.

The following are the components written

---

### FileInput Component

The FileInput component is used as the button and file picker to select images. Its a plain `<input type="file" />`. The native styles are hidden and a custom icon is displayed

```
const FileInput = ({ onChange, children }) => {
  const fileRef = useRef();
  const onPickFile = event => {
    onChange([...event.target.files]);
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "35px",
        height: "35px",
        borderRadius: "3px"
      }}
      onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}
    >
      {children}
      <input
        multiple
        ref={fileRef}
        onChange={onPickFile}
        type="file"
        style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

### Img Component

The Img component displays the images selected from the input. It uses [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a temporary local url that can be populated inside an img tag. This is the image preview seen in the tweet sheet below the textarea.

```
const Img = ({ file, onRemove, index }) => {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
      setFileUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    }
  }, [file]);

  return fileUrl ? (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", maxWidth: "230px", maxHeight: "95px" }}>
      <img
        style={{
          display: "block",
          maxWidth: "230px",
          maxHeight: "95px",
          width: "auto",
          height: "auto"
        }}
        alt="pic"
        src={fileUrl}
      />
      <div
        onClick={() => onRemove(index)}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          width: "20px",
          height: "20px",
          borderRadius: "50%",
          background: "black",
          color: "white",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        x
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

---

### App (Tweet Sheet)

This is the root component that stitches everything together.

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);
  const textAreaRef = useRef();
  const insertAtPos = value => {
    const { current: taRef } = textAreaRef;
    let startPos = taRef.selectionStart;
    let endPos = taRef.selectionEnd;
    taRef.value =
      taRef.value.substring(0, startPos) +
      value.native +
      taRef.value.substring(endPos, taRef.value.length);
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        border: "3px solid",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        width: "600px",
        minHeight: "200px",
        padding: "20px"
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          flex: 1,
          border: "1px solid",
          borderRadius: "5px",
          margin: "0px"
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          ref={textAreaRef}
          value={text}
          style={{ flex: 1, border: "none", minHeight: "150px" }}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            background: "fbfbfb"
          }}
        >
          {pics.map((picFile, index) => (
            <Img
              key={index}
              index={index}
              file={picFile}
              onRemove={rmIndx =>
                setPics(pics.filter((pic, index) => index !== rmIndx))
              }
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          marginTop: "20px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>
          <FileInput onChange={pics => setPics(pics)}>
            <ImgIcon />
          </FileInput>
        </div>
        <EmojiPicker onSelect={insertAtPos} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

### EmojiPickerModal

```
const EmojiPicker = ({ onSelect }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => setShow(oldState => !oldState)}
        style={{
          width: "30px",
          height: "30px",
          borderRadius: "4px",
          border: "3px solid",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          background: "transparent"
        }}
      >
        ej
      </button>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        show && <Picker onSelect={onSelect} />,
        document.body
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Note: For the emoji picker a popular open source emoji picker component [emoji-mart](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart) was used

Comment: I just got to it .. was busy so I am going to work through this myself and give you your bounty

Comment: It says "you may award your bounty in 4 hours" so I will have to wait